# CSSTransition from react-transition-group does not exit

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, css-animations, react-transition-group

Trying to get used CSSTransiction component. I need to show a panel which is animated by using css-classes. The first class defines the primary location, the second defines position when the panel is opened (top: 0).

Appearing is working, but exiting does not. onEntered fires, onExied does not.

There is lack of documentation for CSSTransition component, I tried different combinations, but without success. Any ideas?

CSS:

```
.getSecondLevelPanel{
    position: fixed;
    left: 450px;
    top: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}

.getSecondLevelPanelOpened {
    top: 0;
}
```

React component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

export interface Props {
    isVisible: Boolean;
    children: React.ReactChild;
    onClose: () => void;
}

const SecondLevelPanel = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <CSSTransition
        timeout={{
            enter: 0,
            exit: 500
        }}
        in={props.isVisible}
        appear={true}
        enter={true}
        exit={true}
        classNames={{
            appear: 'getSecondLevelPanel',
            enterDone: 'getSecondLevelPanel getSecondLevelPanelOpened',
            exit: 'getSecondLevelPanel'
        }}
        unmountOnExit={true}
        onEntered={() => {
            alert('entered');
        }}
        onExited={() => {
            alert('exited');
        }}
    >
        <div>
            <a onClick={() => props.onClose()}>Close</a>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    </CSSTransition>
  );
};

export default SecondLevelPanel;
```

Comment: Hey I am running into the same issue, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Actually no, sorry. I would appreciate if you publish your solution when you find it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your CSS and classNames prop. The `CSSTransition` component applies the classes like so.

1. `appear` and `enter` classes are added as soon as the `in` prop is set to true.
2. `appear-active` and `enter-active` are added right after the `appear` and `enter` classes are set.
3. `appear-done` and `enter-done` are added after the duration set in the `timeout` passed.
4. the `exit` classes repeat Step 1-3 just after the `in` prop is set to false.

The reason your exit calls don't work is probably due to only setting one exit class and `0` set to your enter duration. Try setting your transition rule on the `active` classes to ensure that the transition is set for the whole duration of the transition and separate the moving parts from the static ones. Like so

```
.panel{
    position: fixed;
    left: 450px;
    top: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
}

.panel-appear,
.panel-enter {
   top: -100%;
}

.panel-appear-active,
.panel-enter-active {
    top: 0;
    transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}

.panel-exit {
    top: 0;
}

.panel-exit-active {
    top: -100%
    transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
```

Take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/kidunot89/pen/MqRrwN?editors=0110), this is how I create a panel transitions.

Answer (score 3):

After searching for answers for sometime, I realised my problem had to do with my toggle function (onClick={() => props.onClose()} in your case).
It seems my toggle function was not working as it was supposed to. Since onEntered is triggered with "in{true}" and onExited is triggered with "in{false}", you have to make sure the boolean is being changed with each click on your anchor tag.
Looking at your code is seems your onClose function only returns a void function instead of a toggle. Try toggling between true and false and pass that into the in{//toggle function} param.

Answer (score 1):

Install:

```
npm install react-transition-group
```

Usage:

```
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

<CSSTransition
  in={toShow} // boolean value passed via state/props to either mount or unmount this component
  timeout={300}
  classNames='my-element' // IMP!
  unmountOnExit
>
  <ComponentToBeAnimated />
</CSSTransition>
```

NOTE: Make sure to apply below styles using the class property in CSS:

```
.my-element-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.my-element-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
.my-element-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.my-element-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
```